# Updating an array field in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to update my collection which has an array field(initially blank) and for this I am trying this code

```
Industry.update({_id:industryId},
                {$push:{categories: id:categoryId,                                  
                        label:newCategory,
                        value:newCategory }}}});
```

No error is shown, but in my collection just empty documents({}) are created.

Note: I have both `categoryId` and `newCategory`, so no issues with that.
Thanks in advance.

This is the schema:

```
Industry = new Meteor.Collection("industry");

Industry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    label:{
        type:String
    },
    value:{
        type:String
    },
    categories:{
        type: [Object]
    }
}));
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: can you add some sample data showing structure of your collection

Comment: It seems there are more `}` in your codes, could you please update it correctly?

Comment: You are missing one `{` after `categories` , try this `Industry.update({_id:industryId},{$push:{categories: {
                                            id:categoryId,                                 
                                            label:newCategory,
                                            value:newCategory                                           
                                        }}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe the error is occuring because you are not validating 'categories' in your schema. Try adding a 'blackbox:true' to your 'categories' so that it accepts any types of objects.

```
Industry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    label: {
        type: String
    },
    value: {
        type: String
    },
    categories: {
        type: [Object],
        blackbox:true     // allows all objects
    }          
}));
```

Once you've done that try adding values to it like this

```
var newObject = {
    id: categoryId,
    label: newCategory,
    value: newCategory
}
Industry.update({   
    _id: industryId
}, {
    $push: {
        categories: newObject     //newObject can be anything
    }
});
```

This would allow you to add any kind of object into the categories field. 
But you mentioned in a comment that categories is also another collection. 
If you already have a SimpleSchema for categories then you could validate the categories field to only accept objects that match with the SimpleSchema for categories like this

```
Industry.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    label: {
        type: String
    },
    value: {
        type: String
    },
    categories: {
        type: [categoriesSchema]    // replace categoriesSchema by name of SimpleSchema for categories
    }          
}));
```

In this case only objects that match categoriesSchema will be allowed into categories field. Any other type would be filtered out. Also you wouldnt get any error on console for trying to insert other types.(which is what i think is happening when you try to insert now as no validation is specified)

**EDIT : EXPLANATION OF ANSWER**

In a SimpleSchema when you define an array of objects you have to validate it,ie, you have to tell it what objects it can accept and what it can't.
For example when you define it like

```
...
categories: {
    type: [categoriesSchema]    // Correct
}
```

it means that objects that are similar in structure to those in another SimpleSchema named categoriesSchema only can be inserted into it. According to your example any object you try to insert should be of this format

```
{
    id: categoryId,
    label: newCategory,
    value: newCategory
}
```

Any object that isn't of this format will be rejected while insert. Thats why all objects you tried to insert where rejected when you tried initially with your schema structured like this

```
...
categories: {
    type: [Object]     // Not correct as there is no SimpleSchema named 'Object' to match with
}
```

***Blackbox:true***

Now, lets say you don't what your object to be filtered and want all objects to be inserted without validation.
Thats where setting "blackbox:true" comes in. If you define a field like this

```
...
categories: {
    type: [Object],     // Correct
    blackbox:true
}
```

it means that categories can be any object and need not be validated with respect to some other SimpleSchema. So whatever you try to insert gets accepted.

Comment: thanks alot NIjeesh...it did the trick appreciate your help...thank u man

Comment: i will be very thankful if you could explain what blackbox is and how solved my problem

Comment: I have edited the answer with the explanation to answer. And please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if this solved your issue :)

Comment: i came across the same problem again while pushing an array this time and not object....this is the error i am getting("Exception while invoking method 'addKeywords' Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator
")

Comment: can u add the query you used?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query in mongo shell, it will produce a log like matched:1, updated:0.  Please check what you will get . if matched is 0, it means that your input query is not having any matching documents.

Comment: i am using meteor and category is a field in it as well as a seperate collection too

Comment: and since blank {} are getting added in the field that means industryId is found

Comment: if something is not working in mongo apis like meteor or mongo java driver apis, please execute similar query in mongo shell and if it executes properly, then we identify that we have to modify our api methods.     please execute following query in mongoshell and make sure that it is updated properly, <br> db.Industry.update({_id:industryId},{$push:{categories:
id:categoryId,
label:newCategory, value:newCategory
}}}});

Comment: yes i tried this and '0' is shown for everything matched,updated...but i am not understanding this because id do exist in the collection

Comment: I hope that you are executing it like db.Industry.update({_id:'somevalue'},{$push:{categories: id:'somevalue', label:'somevalue', value:'somevalue' }}}});                   If you still get matched as 0, it means that update is not happening because you don't have matching document. Then you have to   use 'Upsert' option for this requirement. Please check the api -https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: sorry it ran successfully on mogoshell

Comment: @user3338256 then it's something wrong with how you define your schema. Please post your schema, we could be able to help you